# What is the 'I' (capital i) flag in C printf?

Tags: c, printf

While compiling the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("99% Invisible");
  return 0;
}
```

in gcc 7.5.0 I get the following warnings:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:16: warning: ' ' flag used with ‘%n’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
   printf("99% Invisible");
                ^
test.c:4:16: warning: 'I' flag used with ‘%n’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
test.c:4:16: warning: format ‘%n’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument [-Wformat=]
   printf("99% Invisible");
             ~~~^
```

What is going on here? I don't see mention of a " " flag or an "I" flag anywhere in documentation. The code outputs `99visible`, essentially ignoring the space and I in the format string and following the %n format.

edit: People seem to be misunderstanding the question. I know how to printf a literal %, and what `%n` do. I am just curious what is happening here.

(also, for those who know the context: I know the system in question didn't use C, I am just curious as to what printf is doing here).

Comment: `%I` is a non-standard format specifier.  For glibc's `printf` implementation, `man 3 printf` states: "For decimal integer conversion (i, d, u) the output uses the locale's alternative output digits, if any." Regardless, if you want a literal `%` character in your printed string, you must escape it (`%%`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `I` flag is a GNU extension to `printf`.  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> glibc 2.2 adds one further flag character.
>
> `I`
>
> For decimal integer conversion (`i`, `d`, `u`) the output uses the
> locale's alternative output digits, if any. For example, since glibc
> 2.2.3 this will give Arabic-Indic digits in the Persian ("fa_IR") locale.

So when the compiler checks the format string, it sees `% In` as a format specifier, i.e. the space and `I` flags applied to the `n` conversion specifier.  Since neither flag is applicable to the `n` conversion specifier, the compiler emits a warning for each.

Answer (score 2):

To print the literal `%`, you must write `%%`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

`I` flag is not in the C standard.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: If the character is K (for instance) as opposed to I, the error message changes to say there is an "unknown conversion type character K". Why is I different from K, then?

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to know what to do with the `I` flag, since it isn't executing the printf. It's just helping out by checking the format, and for that it just needs to know that the `I` is a flag and that flags don't apply to `n` conversions. Evidently, it does know that.

Comment: What is the `I` flag? It is clearly different from an unknown format specifier like `K`, at runtime as well (in my case, printf-ing "99% Kvisible" just outputs the string verbatim, unlike what happens with "99% Invisible").

Comment: The `I` flag is not a valid flag in the C standard.

Comment: @kwsp: it's a valid extension character, as per 7.31.11p1: "Lowercase letters may be added to the conversion specifiers and length modifiers in fprintf and fscanf. Other characters may be used in extensions."

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with your compiler when a `%` character is encountered in a `printf` format string, it scans forward to find a valid format specifier, then interprets everything in-between as a modifier. If those are not valid modifiers, an error is flagged.

As others have pointed out, replace `"99% Invisible"` with `"99%% Invisible"` to fix the problem.